# XML Parsing Error: undefined entity - special characters

Tags: php, xml, special-characters, html-entities

Why does XML display error on certain special characters and some are ok?

For instance, below will create error,

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Customers>
    <Customer>
        <Name>L&ouml;ic</Name>
    </Customer>
</Customers>
```

but this is ok,

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Customers>
    <Customer>
        <Name>&amp;</Name>
    </Customer>
</Customers>
```

I convert the special character through php - `htmlentities('Löic',ENT_QUOTES)` by the way.

How can I get around this?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I found that it works fine if I use numeric character such as `L&#243;ic`

now I have to find how to use php to convert special characters into numeric characters!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are five entities defined in the XML specification — `&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&apos;` and `&quot;`

There are [lots of entities defined in the HTML DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html).

You can't use the ones from HTML in generic XML.

You could use numeric references, but you would probably be better off just getting your [character encodings](http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/tutorial-char-enc/) straight (which basically boils down to:

- [Set your editor](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-setting-encoding-in-applications.en.php) to save the data in UTF-8
- If you process the data with a programming language, make sure it is UTF-8 aware
- If you store the data in a database, make sure it is configured for UTF-8
- When you serve up your document, make sure the HTTP headers specify that it is UTF-8 (in the case of XML, UTF-8 is the default, so not specifying anything is almost as good)

)

Comment: Dorward: Thanks. I tried with this iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', 'Löic'), it then gives me this error - <b>Notice</b>:  iconv() [<a href='function.iconv'>function.iconv</a>]: Detected an incomplete multibyte character in input string in...

Comment: +1, but he still needs to use numeric entities for those characters that are forbidden in XML (for instance, U+0003).

Comment: Yes, UTF-8 won't help any if you're trying to send &nbsp; or &ouml; in XML.

Comment: @mikato — Yes it will. Both those character can be represented as literal characters in any unicode encoding (and the named entities you quote don't exist in plain XML)

Comment: I'm talking about actually sending/receiving "&nbsp;", not its HTML translation of a space character. Those are not recognized XML entities and a parser may throw an error. For example, Firefox says: "XML Parsing Error: undefined entity" when receiving XML data including a &nbsp; and it actually highlights the entity in the error message. Chrome says similar "error on line x at column y: Entity 'nbsp' not defined". This is with everything using UTF-8.

Comment: @mikato — Then the only special character you have to worry about is `&`, which you have to represent as `&amp;` as I said in the answer … or you could use a CDATA block.

Comment: @Quentin Good point. I guess same for the other 4 invalid XML characters.

Answer (score 3):

Because it is not an built-in entity, it is instead an external entity that needs declaration in DTD.

Answer (score 0):

#### TLDR Solution

You can solve this problem with [**`html_entity_decode()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) (Source: PHP.net), like so...

```
$xml_line = '<description>' . html_entity_decode($description) . '</description>';
```

#### Full, Working Demo Online

In this demo, I use `&rsquo;` and a line from the *Tao teh Ching* to demonstrate the above use of `html_entity_decode()`...

```
$title = 'The name you can say isn&rsquo;t the real name.';
$xml_title = html_entity_decode($title)
$xml_title = str_replace(['<', '>',], ['&lt;', '&gt;',], $xml_title );
$xml_line = '<title>' . $xml_title . '</title>';
print($xml_line);
```

Don't forget to replace back those `<` and `>` chars, though!

[**Working Demo Sandbox**](https://ideone.com/3qKOKi)

#### How Do You Know It Worked?

Want to verify it worked just fine?  Then head on over to the [**W3C RSS Feed Validator**](https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi), and see the above code being approved as just fine.