# Convert special characters to ISO Latin-1 codes with php?

Tags: php, xml, special-characters

Follow up on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787700/xml-parsing-error-undefined-entity-special-characters) I made earlier on.

I found out XML actually takes numeric codes instead of name codes when dealing with special characters. So I have looked through online on how to convert special characters into numberic codes, but I haven't got any lucks.

Do I have to write a function to do this task or does php come with any default function which can save up lots of works?

For instance, I want to convert `á` to `&#225;` but **not** `á` to  `&aacute;`

Is it possible?

Please help if you have any ideas.

**EDIT:**

I am using this suggestion to convert the special chars into numberic chars,

```
$txt = preg_replace('/([\x80-\xff])/e', "'&#' . ord('$1') . ';'", $txt);
```

but I just found out that it does not convert these 5 special chars into numberic codes - `<`, `>`, `&`, `'` and `"`.

How can I get around them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic approach is to use:

```
$txt = preg_replace('/([\x80-\xff])/e', "'&#' . ord('$1') . ';'", $txt);
```

You must ensure that $txt does indeed contain Latin-1 already (`utf8_decode`), because you'd otherwise receive the wrong value from the string byte.

Comment: Seeing his original question, the XML document is in UTF-8, not Latin-1 (the encoding is not specified, so it defaults to UTF-8).

Comment: @Artefacto: Oh I see. I went blindly by the title here, and hoped that Latin-1 and Unicode enumeration is mostly identical anyway. Well, he has to try what works..

Comment: @mario: thanks. it seems to work fine - echo preg_replace('/([\x80-\xff])/e', "'&#' . ord('$1') . ';'", "ö"); and I get &#246; which is what I am after. thanks!

Comment: @mario: just found out the code you suggest does not convert these characters into numberic codes - <, >, &, ' and ". how can I get around them?

Comment: @lauthiamkok: If you want them converted too, include them into the square brackes `[<\'"&>\x80-\xff]` in the regex

Answer (score 1):

Use [`mb_encode_numericentity`](http://php.net/mb_encode_numericentity). Example (assuming the script is encoded in UTF-8):

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/plain");
echo mb_encode_numericentity("aáb",
    array(0x0080, 0x10FFFF, 0x0, 0xFFFFFF), "UTF-8");
```

would give:

```
a&#225;b
```

This example encodes to their numeric entities all the characters that are not in ASCII. If you also want to encode the characters `<`, `>`, `&`, `'` and `"`, which have special meaning in XML, use `htmlspecialchars` (or use `mb_encode_numericentity`, but adding those characters to the array in the second argument).

Note, however, that if your XML file is encoded in UTF-8, you only need to encode a few characters (`á` is not one of them). See [here](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/web/php-bugs/trunk/include/functions.php?r1=305240&r2=305239&pathrev=305240) for an appropriate conversion map to use in `mb_encode_numericentity` (this includes the conversion of the XML special characters `<`, `>`, `&`, `'` and `"` and also encodes characters that are forbidden to appear literally in a XML document, like U+0000).

Comment: Do you have the full map to make this useful?

Comment: @cyberwiki What are you talking about? Useful for what? This converts LATIN-1 characters which are not in ASCII to their numeric entities. As a bonus it also converts all other higher unicode character. If he wants to escape `<`, `>`, `&`, `'` and `"` he can use `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: Well done for identifying the array values that identify non-ASCII characters, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A neat function is presented here http://www.sourcerally.net/Scripts/39-Convert-HTML-Entities-to-XML-Entities.  You chain html_entities to the function presented to get text->html->xml

No, php has no built in function to date like `xml_entities`

Comment: The page you linked to has incorrect information. It starts "Input a string with html entities like &amp; and get the correct xml entities back - in this case &#160;". This is misleading. `&amp;` is a valid entity in all XML documents, along with `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&quot;` and `&apos;`.

Comment: And btw, if you wanted to decode html entities for use in a XML document, you could use `html_entity_decode`.

Comment: @artefacto - trigger happy are we. It is a starting point. You can always chain through html_entities to get html for further conversion to xml. The html entities is a pretty good list of what is needed for xml.

Comment: @artefacto `if you wanted to decode html entities for use in a XML document` It is the other way around, follow question link to OP's other question.

Comment: You linked to a page with wrong information, what would you expect? Now you edit with another inanity like "You chain html_entities to the function presented to get text->html->xml", which is not even grammatically correct... The downvote is deserved, sorry.