# How to use special characters in XML

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, special-characters

I am writing a query in XML in my SSRS report. I can use "& lt;"(less than) without any problem but not able to use "& le;" CData also doesn't work in my query it gets completely ifnored (less than equal).Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML Parsing Error: undefined entity - special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787700/xml-parsing-error-undefined-entity-special-characters)

Answer (score 1):

What character(s) were you hoping that `&le;` would refer to?

(Perhaps "<="? or perhaps "≤"?)

You can either define an entity that expands `&le;` to the required character(s), or you can enter the required characters in the file directly, in place of the entity reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try using escaped sequence for less than equal to like below

```
&lt;=
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be doing the comparison.